Multiple macro definitions from a comma-separated list
I want to write a command that defines style macros in bulk. The first parameter is the style modifier (for example, \bf\Huge), the second should be a comma-separated list of words w_i. For each word w_i, the command should define a macro with name \w_i that prints w_i with the style modifier applied.
In the following snippet, \style is a command that can do the above for one word w_i rather than a comma-separated list:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\style}[2]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{{#1{#2}}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfunc[2]{\@for\tmp:=#2\do{\style{#1}{\tmp}}}
\makeatother

\style{\mathbb}{Q}
\style{\bf\Huge}{Set}
\myfunc{\bf}{Grp,Top}

\begin{document}
$\Q$ \Set %\Grp \Top
\end{document}

The original version of \myfunc is taken from David Carlisle's answer here, I tried to modify it so it would accept a second (actually, first) argument. However, if one removes % in the above code, LaTeX gives an error ! Undefined control sequence. \tmp ->\@nil.
What am I doing wrong and which parts of the manuals should I read? (Or probably questions this one is a duplicate of, I was unable to find them.) For such a basic operation, I'd like to understand what happens at the low level (plain TeX or LaTeX) rather than use an existing solution from some package.

unrelated but \bf hasn't been defined by default in latex since 1993, are you really still using it in new documents?

I removed the plain-tex tag

If you add

\show\Grp
\show\Top

to see the definitions you have made,you will see that the comamnds are defined to be:
> \Grp=\long macro:
->{\bf {\tmp }}.
l.14 \show\Grp
              
? 
> \Top=\long macro:
->{\bf {\tmp }}.
l.15 \show\Top
            

so you ae defining every command in the list in terms of \tmp (which gets set to \@nil at the end of the list, hence the error.
Adding some control over the expansion order produces
> \Grp=\long macro:
->{\bfseries {Grp}}.
l.15 \show\Grp
              
? 
> \Top=\long macro:
->{\bfseries {Top}}.
l.16 \show\Top


updated test file:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\style}[2]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{{#1{#2}}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfunc[2]{\@for\tmp:=#2\do{%
    \expanded{\unexpanded{\style{#1}}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\tmp}}}}}
\makeatother

\style{\mathbb}{Q}
\style{\bfseries\Huge}{Set}
\myfunc{\bfseries}{Grp,Top}

\show\Grp
\show\Top

\begin{document}
$\Q$ \Set \Grp \Top
\end{document}

Control over expansion was a main design aim of expl3, not surprisingly it's easier with expl3
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\style}[2]{\cs_new:cpn{#2}{{#1{#2}}}}

\newcommand\myfunc[2]{
  \clist_map_inline:nn
  {#2}
  {\style{#1}{##1}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\style{\mathbb}{Q}
\style{\bfseries\Huge}{Set}
\myfunc{\bfseries}{Grp,Top}

\show\Grp
\show\Top

\begin{document}
$\Q$ \Set \Grp \Top
\end{document}


I think I more or less understood the problem (I did not know about \show), thank you so much! The \expandafter in your definition operates on three tokens {,\tmp,}, is that right?

@Amateur_Algebraist expandafer works on two tokens \expandafter\a\b first expands \b then control returns to \a so \expandafter{\tmp  expands \tmp before the { is seen so the definition ends up with the expansion fo \tmp not \tmp itself.

Remarks:

In other answers you were already told about \Huge in math-mode and about \bf in LaTeX 2ε.

The approach presented by egreg is much more flexible than anything presented in this answer:

Due to the possibility within the first argument of \style of denoting via #1 the text phrase coming from an item of the comma-list of the second argument of \style, the text phrase can be nested inside levels of curly braces as deeply as needed.
The extracting of items from the comma-list is much better with \clist_map_inline:nn than it is with \@for: With \clist_map_inline:nn empty/blank comma-list items are not mapped but skipped. With \clist_map_inline:nn spaces and one level of curly braces surrounding a comma-list-item are stripped off.


According to historical comments labeled as "not necessarily accurate any more"(!!!) in file ltcntrl.dtx of source2e.pdf syntax of \@for is:

\@for NAME := LIST \do {BODY}:
Assumes that LIST expands to A1,A2,... ,An.
Executes BODY n times, with NAME = Ai on the i-th iteration.
Optimized for the normal case of n = 1. Works for n=0.

I.e., LIST is "hit" by \expandafter once. So let's prepend \@empty to the list when passing it in directly instead of passing in a macro that expands to the list.

The last time the author of this answer looked into source2e.pdf, the comments about the syntax of \@for seemed still accurate. However, unlike \clist_map_inline:nn, the macro\@for is not an official but an internal interface of LaTeX 2ε. There is no warranty that it might not be changed in future LaTeX releases in a way where examples of this answer are broken.



With your code \myfunc's \tmp goes unexpanded into the ⟨balanced text⟩ of the ⟨definition⟩ of the macro to define. Expanding and exchanging macro arguments is a vintage technique for resolving such  expansion-issues.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand{\style}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand
  \expandafter*%
  \csname#2\endcsname{{#1{#2}}}%
}%
\newcommand\myfunc[2]{%
  \@for\tmp:={\@empty#2}\do{%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\tmp}{\style{#1}}%
    %\expandafter\show\csname\tmp\endcsname
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\style{\mathbb}{Q}
\style{\Huge\textbf}{Set}
\myfunc{\textbf}{Grp,Top}

\begin{document}
$\Q$ \Set \Grp \Top
\end{document}

If you like, you can add a bit of \romannumeral-expansion and have \style process a comma-list directly:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\@ifdefinable\@stopromannumeral{\chardef\@stopromannumeral=`\^^00 }%
\newcommand\style[2]{%
  \@for\tmp:={\@empty#2}\do{%
    \expandafter\newcommand
    \expandafter*%
    \csname\tmp\expandafter\endcsname
               \expandafter{%
               \expandafter{%
                 \romannumeral
                 \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond
                 \expandafter{\tmp}{\@stopromannumeral#1}%
               }}%
    %\expandafter\show\csname\tmp\endcsname
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\style{\mathbb}{Q,R,Z,C}
\style{\Huge\textbf}{Set}
\style{\textbf}{Grp,Top}

\begin{document}
$\Q$ $\R$ $\Z$ $\C$\Set \Grp \Top
\end{document}

If you like to have the possibility to denote the text phrase as #1 in the first argument of \style, a vintage-code-solution can be based on \csname..\endcsname-expansion:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\style[2]{%
  \@for\tmp:={\@empty#2}\do{%
    \begingroup
    \expandafter\def\csname\tmp\endcsname##1{#1}%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\newcommand
    \expandafter*%
    \csname
    \tmp
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \endcsname
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            {%
      \csname\tmp\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\tmp}%
    }%
    %\expandafter\show\csname\tmp\endcsname
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\style{\mathbb{#1}}{Q,R,Z,C}
\style{\text{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily #1}}{Set,Grp,Top}

\begin{document}
$\Q$ $\R$ $\Z$ $\C$ \Set \space \Grp \space \Top
\end{document}

If you like some cleanup with scratch macros, you can have TeX carry out \@for in a local scope and accumulate \newcommand-directives within a token-register—this way you can (theoretically) use \style to define \@tmp if you want...:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\style[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \toks@{\endgroup}%
  \def\@tmp##1{#1}%
  \begingroup
  \def\@tmp{#2}%
  \@for\@tmp:=\@tmp\do{%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\toks@
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            {%<-opening brace of \toks@-assignment
    \expandafter\the
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \toks@
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \newcommand
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            *%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \csname\@tmp\expandafter\endcsname
                \expandafter\expandafter
                \expandafter{%<-opening brace of \newcommand-assignment
                \expandafter\@tmp
                \expandafter{\@tmp}%
    }%<-closing brace of \newcommand-assignment
    }%<-closing brace of \toks@-assignment
    \begingroup
  }%
  \endgroup
  \the\toks@
  %\begingroup
  %\def\@tmp{#2}%
  %\@for\@tmp:=\@tmp\do
  %  {\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\show\csname\@tmp\endcsname\begingroup}%
  %\endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\style{\mathbb{#1}}{Q,R,Z,C}
\style{\text{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily #1}}{Set,Grp,Top}

\begin{document}
$\Q$ $\R$ $\Z$ $\C$ \Set \space \Grp \space \Top
\end{document}


I see big problems with your idea:

\bf has been deprecated for 30 years
\Huge doesn't work in math mode (although it seems to)

I guess that \Set and \Grp will be used in math mode to denote categories, so even using \bfseries inside a box wouldn't be good: try
\newcommand{\Set}{\text{\bfseries\Huge Set}}

and use \Set inside the statement of a theorem: besides “Set” being absurdely large in context, the text would be printed in italics.
Let's forget about \Huge for the sake of typography and study a way out.
Of course, the method would be to use \mathbf rather than \bfseries (not \bf, please).
Here's a method, where the parameter is passed to a temporary command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\DeclareMathOperator{\obj}{obj}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\style}{mm}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__amateur_style:n {\exp_not:n {#1}}
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpe {##1} { \__amateur_style:n {##1} }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\style{\mathbb{#1}}{Q}

\style{\text{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily #1}}{Set,Grp}

\begin{document}

$\Q$ is a field, $\Set$ is an important category.

\begin{theorem}
If $G\in\obj(\Grp)$ then $G$ is a group.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


The code can actually be simplified, thanks to Ulrich Diez:
\NewDocumentCommand{\style}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#2} { \cs_new_protected:cpn {##1} {#1} }
 }


\bf\Huge would be of little use in a real text, it's just there to illustrate what I meant by a 'style modifier' (the main interest was how to do this "functional programming" trick; I could have easily hardcoded the 3 or 5 modifiers I use).
Regarding \bf, I know that it is deprecated, but the name is shorter and I hope I'll never have to use bold-italic (are there any other reasons \bf is 'bad' besides the NFSS?)

Now that I think about it, in the Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V era someone would copy my \bf and then have a difficult time debugging their in-theorem definitions to look as they intend to. I am sorry, I'll try to avoid using \bf in public :-)
BTW, I'm baffled by theorem statements being italicized by default in amsthm. My native language uses a non-Latin script, and a theorem in italics just looks ugly (that's a personal preference though). But in Latin script, small words are easily confused with parts of equations.

@Amateur_Algebraist For the last problem, do \theoremstyle{definition} before any \newtheorem.

@UlrichDiez Because I didn't think to it!
